# Bootstrap: unequal columns on stacked

Tags: bootstrap-4, responsive

I'm trying to get a 50/50 layout, with half the row filled with a picture and half the row has text. It currently works on desktop, laptop, and tablet. On mobile (when its stacked) though, the image isn't half the row for some reason.

Can someone explain why?

https://imgur.com/a/FNTzWwE

html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row row_box grey">
                    <div class="col-md-6 padding_0">
                        <div class="homepage_imgs meats"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 homepage_text">
                        <p class="homepage_headers">Meats</p>
                        <p class="homepage_subheaders">Steak, Chicken, Fish, Burger, Eggs, Turkey</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

css:

```
.row_box
{
    height:88vh;
    height:calc(var(--vh, 1vh) * 88);
}
.grey
{
    background-color:#e6e6e6;
}
.padding_0
{
    padding:0;
}
.order
{
    order: 2;
}
.homepage_imgs
{
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
.meats
{
    background-image: url("beef-cuisine-cut-1881336.jpg");

.homepage_text
{
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    text-align:center;
    align-items:center;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    color: #404040;
    hyphens: auto;
}
.homepage_headers
{
    font-size: calc(5em + .5vw);
    color: #e67300;
}
.homepage_subheaders
{
    font-size: calc(1.5em + .5vw);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your using col-md-6 which assigns each div to take up six columns when the screen width is wider than 992px. Just use col-6 as it applies to all screen sizes.

```php
<div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row row_box grey">
                    <div class="col-6 padding_0">
                        <div class="homepage_imgs meats"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6 homepage_text">
                        <p class="homepage_headers">Meats</p>
                        <p class="homepage_subheaders">Steak, Chicken, Fish, Burger, Eggs, Turkey</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think you guys misunderstood my question. I *want* it to be stacked on xs and sm. Thats why I used col-md-6, so that it stacks below md. But the problem is that when it stacks, the columns are no longer the same size (as shown in the pictures).

Comment: @AProgrammerZ ahh i see. You could use CSS to set the height of both elements only on smaller devices.

Comment: But why does it happen in the first place? Shouldn't bootstrap do it automatically?

Answer (score 0):

This should work, you responsive classes are targeted from medium (`col-md-6`) and up. You should start from extra small viewport. In BS4 its col-* in your case it should be `col-6`

```
<div class="col-6 padding_0">
                        <div class="homepage_imgs meats"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6 homepage_text">
                        <p class="homepage_headers">Meats</p>
                        <p class="homepage_subheaders">Steak, Chicken, Fish, Burger, Eggs, Turkey</p>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think you guys misunderstood my question. I *want* it to be stacked on xs and sm. Thats why I used col-md-6, so that it stacks below md. But the problem is that when it stacks, the columns are no longer the same size (as shown in the pictures).

Comment: @AProgrammerZ you mean the height is not same?

Comment: ya, even though its looks perfectly equal above sm

Comment: Try this approach https://codepen.io/nerdpruitt/pen/zxkfH Target only xm and sm using media queries